# UIView cut out any number of transparent holes

Tags: ios

I want to a UIView can have any number of transparent holes. I tried UIBezierPath with UsesEvenOddFillRule to be true. But there is no luck, with one hole is OK, with any number of holes, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw a circles/ellipse with below code:

```
class HolyView: UIView {

  var holes: [CGRect] = [] {
      didSet {
          setNeedsDisplay()
      }
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      super.draw(rect)

      for hole in holes {
          let intersection = rect.intersection(hole)
          let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

          if intersection.intersects(rect) {
              context?.setFillColor(self.backgroundColor?.cgColor ?? UIColor.clear.cgColor)
              context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.clear)
              context?.fillEllipse(in: intersection)
          }
       }
    }
}
```

**OR Using BezierPath:**

```
class BeziHolyView: UIView {

  var holes: [CGRect] = [] {
      didSet {
          setNeedsDisplay()
      }
  }

  override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
      super.draw(rect)

      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
      context?.clear(rect)

      let clipPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
      for hole in holes {
          clipPath.append(UIBezierPath(roundedRect: hole, cornerRadius: hole.height/2))
      }

      clipPath.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
      clipPath.addClip()
      backgroundColor?.setFill()
      clipPath.fill()
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
let view = HolyView/BeziHolyView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
view.holes = [CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 20, height: 20),
              CGRect(x: 80, y: 30, width: 20, height: 20)]
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the first method, because it can handle the case that holes are overlapping.

Comment: A small issue, the holes are black color, not transparent.

Comment: Just set the `context`'s `fillColor` to `backgroundColor`. This will fix the issue. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Need to set self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor; in the initialiser also.